# How to make the tab stick in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

For example if I use the Insert tab and then click in the document, the Ribbon goes back to Home. How to make the Insert tab stick, that is for Word to stay on the last tab I have used?

Comment: It doesn't go back to Home, unless you click on Home or scroll up with the mouse with your pointer in the ribbon. It generally stays in the last used tab

Comment: @Pratyush Nalam see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears when you clicked "Collapse the Ribbon" or the Word is set up with it. It is not a bug, but rather something a novice might not know. To solve it, go to the right of the ribbon and pin it-there is a small pin that you click. Or right click and uncheck "Collapse the Ribbon".

Comment: Ah now I get it!